# Can Snowsql's prompt_format be conditional?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to set the prompt conditionally, based on which connection (environment) has been made. I can of course set the prompt to the default prompt so that when I start snowsql it has the correct name, but as soon as I do `!connect something` this will be incorrect.

I have several ways in which I might dynamically determine which environment I am in (it's part of the warehouse name that I could substr out, or if I could set a variable each time a new `!connect` is made).

Is this possible?

Renaming the warehouses themselves for this purpose is, I hope for obvious reasons, not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get your idea how to differentiate the environments, but I suggest considering the config files. You can set prompt_format and other connection parameters as you want then choose between them when connecting.

Example:

config_prod file

```
[options]
prompt_format="[#FF0000][user]@[database][schema]|[warehouse]>"

[connections]
accountname = <account>
username = <username>
password = xxxxxx
role=<prod_role>
dbname = <prod_db>
schemaname=<prod_schema>
warehousename = <prod_wh>
```

config_dev file

```
[options]
prompt_format="[#00FF00][user]@[database][schema]|[warehouse]>"

[connections]
accountname = <account>
username = <username>
password = xxxxxx
role=<dev_role>
dbname = <dev_db>
schemaname=<dev_schema>
warehousename = <prod_wh>
```

Then you connect using either:
`snowsql --config /path/to/config_prod`
or
`snowsql --config /path/to/config_dev`

In my example you should see red color for prod and green for dev.
Since the `prompt_format` is a configuration option and not a connection parameter it is not possible to change it based on the connection name within one running instance of SnowSQL, and you will need to run different instances of SnowSQL app to see the changes from the different config files applied. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but since I won't quit snowsql but just do a !connect <x> to switch to another (no need for each connection to have its own config)...

Comment: @JohnO Unfortunately, the prompt_format is a configuration option, it can be applied from a config file or ```-o``` argument when snowsql invoked, or using ```!set``` option in the current session. I believe in your case ```!set```will work, but so far I do not see a clever way to automate it after a connection was made or exited. A first thing that comes to my mind is using ```[variables]``` section of the config file, where you can define variables like ```varname='"promt_format=[#FF00000]etc..."'``` then just using !set=varname you will change the prompt, but again not ideal in your case